# container "sonarqube" in pod "sonar-574d99bfb5-dr8nx" is waiting to start: CreateContainerConfigError

Tags: sonarqube

i am facing a problem with my sonar i've been trying to set it up but i get this error from : **kubectl logs sonar-574d99bfb5-dr8nx -n sonar** == container "sonarqube" in pod "sonar-574d99bfb5-dr8nx" is waiting to start: CreateContainerConfigError.
and when i do describe : **kubectl describe pod sonar-574d99bfb5-dr8nx -n sonar**
i get this :

```
Name:         sonar-574d99bfb5-dr8nx
Namespace:    sonar
Priority:     0
Node:         master01/192.168.137.136
Start Time:   Tue, 22 Mar 2022 20:30:16 +0000
Labels:       app=sonar
              pod-template-hash=574d99bfb5
Annotations:  cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 734ba33acb9e2c007861112ffe7c1fce84fa3a434494a0df6951a7b4b6b8dacb
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.42.241.105/32
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.42.241.105/32
Status:       Pending
IP:           10.42.241.105
IPs:
  IP:           10.42.241.105
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/sonar-574d99bfb5
Containers:
  sonarqube:
    Container ID:
    Image:          sonarqube:latest
    Image ID:
    Port:           9000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CreateContainerConfigError
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      memory:  2Gi
    Requests:
      memory:  1Gi
    Environment Variables from:
      sonar-config  ConfigMap  Optional: false
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /opt/sonarqube/data/ from app-pvc (rw,path="data")
      /opt/sonarqube/extensions/ from app-pvc (rw,path="extensions")
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-q22lb (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  app-pvc:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  sonar-pvc
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-q22lb:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  12m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned sonar/sonar-574d99bfb5-dr8nx to master01
  Warning  Failed     10m (x12 over 12m)    kubelet            Error: stat /home/mtst/data-sonar-pvc: no such file or directory
  Normal   Pulled     2m24s (x50 over 12m)  kubelet            Container image "sonarqube:latest" already present on machine
```

here's my pvc yaml :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: sonar-pv
  namespace: sonar
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 3Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/home/mtst/data-sonar-pvc"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: sonar-pvc
  namespace: sonar
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

if there's anything that can help me resolve my issue i would appreciate it.
thank you.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's in the error message: `Error: stat /home/mtst/data-sonar-pvc: no such file or directory`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the [awx postgres](https://github.com/ansible/awx-operator) deployment.

Credit goes to [Kubernetes 1.17.2 Rancher 2.3.5 CreateContainerConfigError: stat no such file or directory but the directory IS there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61056886/kubernetes-1-17-2-rancher-2-3-5-createcontainerconfigerror-stat-no-such-file-or) for resolving the issue for me.

Running a Rancher kubernetes cluster and wanting custom PV I needed to add the below type to my `PersistentVolume` definition:

```yaml
  hostPath:
    path: "/home/mtst/data-sonar-pvc"
    type: "DirectoryOrCreate"
```